# Error Trigger: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512:

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-update

I have written an after-update trigger that recomputes the percentages for all rows in the last column whenever one of the numbers in the amount column changes. Please help me get rid of the mutate error.

| FRUITNAME | AMOUNT | PERC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 10 | null |
| Pears | 20 | null |
| Bananas | 6 | null |
| Orange | 10 | null |
| Pineapples | 4 | null |

```
create or replace trigger fruit_perc
after update of AMOUNT
ON FRUIT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    TOTAL NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT PERC, AMOUNT, SUM(amount) AS TOTAL FROM FRUIT group by PERC, AMOUNT)
    LOOP
        
        i.PERC := (i.AMOUNT/i.TOTAL) * 100;
        INSERT INTO FRUIT(PERC) VALUES(i.PERC); 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.amount);
    END LOOP;
END;
/


update FRUIT
set AMOUNT = 4
WHERE AMOUNT = 4;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

The mutating table error almost always points to poor design, usually a broken data model. It arises when we have a trigger which executes DML on the table which owns the trigger. This is a problem because triggers fire during a transaction: when the trigger fires the state of the table is in flux, so it is impossible for the trigger to derive the accurate state of the tables data.

Consider your UPDATE statement: if the SET clause was `set amount = amount+1` how could the trigger possible calculate PERC *for each row*? Is TOTAL the sum of the amounts before the UPDATE? At the end of the update? Some form of rolling total which accumulates as the statement processes each row? Who can tell? Certainly the kernel can't, and that's why it hurls ORA-4091.

Presumably this is homework. PERC is a classic example of the sort of column we don't include in tables because it is more efficient to derive it in SQL when we need it, rather than maintain it in every DML statement on the table.

The proper way to project the column would be like this:

```
with cte as (
  select sum(amount) as tot
  from fruit)
select fruit.fruitname
      ,fruit.amount
      ,(fruit.amount/cte.tot) as perc
from fruit
cross join cte
/
```

Comment: To put the first paragraph (specifically poor design) into a more simple perspective: This error exists to prevent the developer from creating an infinite loop. This basically means that the trigger can generally not able to operate on the table it is being triggered on.